# Emulator can not be used without HAXM, what to do?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cpu

My CPU does not support VT-x. Thats why i cant install HAXM. Since the update the emulater does not work anymore without HAXM, which is really messed up?

Anyone got an idea on how to solve this Problem? Or is there an alternative Emulator or something?

Comment: great alternative for the official emulator: https://www.genymotion.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your bios if computer really not have these virtualization options. Maybe it is little hidded. Alternative 3rd party emulators are bluestacks or genymotion. I recommend to check the second one.

Comment: I checked every little corner in my bios. It's nowhere to be found. I have an intel i5 2500 btw. I think the 2500k supports it and i also thought i would have 2500k in my Computer. Which is why i dont get it anymore.

Comment: Can you tell me model of your motherboard? I am almost 100% percent sure that this cpu support Intel VT

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/products/52209/Intel-Core-i5-2500-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz Intel pages are saying that this technology is supported so we need to keep on searching

Comment: I am pretty sure it is an MSI P67A-C43 or P67S-C43

Comment: Google says that you should look for it in cpu or overclocking options. Seems strange but it is possible

Comment: How can people be so blind, meaning me :D

Comment: Maybe it is just because you were tired looking for it. If just happens sometimes. I am glad that I could help You.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I checked every little corner in my bios. It's nowhere to be found. I have an intel i5 2500 btw. I think the 2500k supports it and i also thought i would have 2500k in my Computer. Which is why i dont get it anymore.

Comment: http://ark.intel.com/m/de/products/52209/Intel-Core-i5-2500-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_70-GHz#@product/specifications

Answer (score 0):

Well, after giving it a brief search all I can say is try to update yor BIOS to the latest available, and then search under the "System Information/Overclocking/CPU Feature" section and see whether you can see something related to it:

https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=3jdaoibv16jart0rgkpuvige47&topic=148677.msg1104946#msg1104946

There is where I found the related info, good luck with that.

If not, the Genymotion option is also worth giving it a try.

www.genymotion.com